# OpenSSL - 1.0 wont install keeps installing 0.9.8

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I have tried installing OpenSSL 1.0 and 1.0.1 but everytime I install it - it reverts to 0.9.8 I have done apt-get remove openssl and apt-get autoremove before each install and made sure it was uninstalled.

Running Ubuntu 10.04

Thanks in advance.

OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009

Comment: are you sure you're running 1.0.1 OpenSSL when you check the version?

Comment: No it says it is 0.9.8 when I check version but I am installing 1.0+

Comment: Type `which openssl` to see where which openssl you are running.  Is that where the new version was installed?  If not, you'll need to modify your path to point to the new version ahead of the old version.